# CPU minutes exhausted on a wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, server

I am currently using Linux hosting for my [wordpress website](http://careersinnonprofits.com/) .

Recently I got an email from the hosting provider to maintain the resources used by the website so I logged in to my Cpanel to see what was wrong. So I found that the CPU minutes have been exhausted.

So i used w3 cache, super cache etc to see if anyone of the plugins could help me out but it didn't work. 
I used [WP Server Stats](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-server-stats/) to see that if anything was wrong with the word press but the results were normal.

Now the hosting provider has limited my max number of processes but still can't get the minutes to decrease. I have used all other plugins but nothing seems to work.

[image: cpu time exhausted]

After that I have also tried decreasing the google crawl rate but it also didn't work. But I saw unusual link in crawl errors.
[image: google crawl results]

Is that interrelated.If so what can I do to fix this .

Any help would be greatly appreciated . Thanks

Comment: and can the down voter explain the reason to down vote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using cloudflare.
Scan your site for viruses with clamAv.
Maybe hacker broke into your site and he is stealing your resources.
Also you can try to download access and error logs from cpanel and take a look if anything strange happens.
Your hosting provider should be able to tell you if some script in particular is using CPU resources so excessively. Maybe some plugin?